# What is the difference between nullabe and non-nullable type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, null, nullable, kotlin-null-safety

Please explain the difference between nullable and non-nullable type. I am new to kotlin and i am confused. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nullable** types can hold **nulls**. When type is nullable the question mark is set after it's type:

```
val str: String? = null
```

**Non-nullable** types can't hold **nulls**:

```
val str: String = "some value"
```

If we try to set **null** value to **Non-nullable** type, IDE will give an error and code will not be compiled:

```
val str: String = null // error, the code won't compile
```

[Here you can read more about **Null Safety**.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

Answer (score 0):

when a variable has a nullable type then the variable can have value or it can also have value null and the program will not force close like most java based programs with **null pointer exeption** error messages.

for example :

```
val data: DataResponse? = null
```

its more save then you use **val data: String** because when your **data** variabel dont have value or null when you use it your program not force close at that time.
you can use your **data** variabel like this:

```
your_text.text = data
```

and your code will not force close.

but if your code like this, it means **nonNullable**.

```
val data: DataResponse
```

your apps will force close at that time you use your variabel